# How do I unit test functions in my R package that interact with the file system?

Tags: r, unit-testing, testthat

I'm working on an R package at work. My package has gotten large enough that I've decided I need some form of repeatable testing. I settled upon using `testthat` and `mockery`. I'm not a developer, so this is the first time I'm writing tests at this level.

I deal with a lot of data files and it's very convenient to have functions in my package to help locate files. These functions interact with the file system via calls to `dir`. For example,

- Data from one event can be split over multiple files. If I have file `datafile_2017.10.20_12.00.00`, I have a function that can find the next file that is part of the same event, i.e. `datafile_2017.10.20_12.05.00`.

My question is this: what is the best way to test functions like this? My intuition is to avoid using actual files stored somewhere else in my repository because that can fail for a number of reasons, e.g. different paths, different repo states b/w systems. I searched around and it looks like different languages have mocking libraries that allow for mocking directory structures. I haven't found anything like that for R (except for [testthatsomemore](https://github.com/robertzk/testthatsomemore), but it was removed from CRAN sometime in 2016).

Is there an R package that allows for mocking directory structures? Or am I wrong to move away from storing small test files in my repo?

Comment: If you include sample data in your package, you can access it with `system.file` in a way that will work independent of OS or filesystem. [`rio` has lots of examples.](https://github.com/leeper/rio/tree/master/tests/testthat)

Comment: @alistaire Thank you, that's a good tip. I wasn't aware of `system.file` before. If I do go that route, it should be useful.